# Changing parameter annotations with decorators

Tags: python, parameters, typechecking

This one has stumped me for a while, and I'm not sure if it's possible.

I want to change a function parameter's annotation and have it affect the type checker. I was thinking maybe a [Pep 612](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0612/) workaround could be used?

I've been doing some light tests, either with `function.__annotations__` or doing what I've done in the example... all with no luck. You can see what I've dabbled with below:

```py
from typing import (
    Callable,
    Literal,
    TypeVar,
    Generic,
    Any
)
import functools
import inspect

from discord import Member

T = TypeVar('T')
V = TypeVar('V')

class Option(Generic[T, V]):
    pass


def change_decorator_func(f) -> Callable[..., Any]:
    
    @functools.wraps(f)
    def wrapped(*args, **kwargs) -> Any:
        sig = inspect.signature(f)
        for name, param in sig.parameters.items():
            param.replace(annotation=Member)
        
        return f(*args, **kwargs)
    
    return wrapped
    

@change_decorator_func
def foo(this: Option[Member, Literal['This is a test']]) -> None:
    this.display_name 
    # Cannot access member "display_name" for type "Option[Unknown, Literal['This is a test']]"
    # Member "display_name" is unknown
```

Any insight you may have is appreciated!